# Saving from dictionary to file (error)

Tags: python

I'm taking my first Python class so please bear with me, I have ZERO experience in programming but I'm very eager to learn. If you could steer me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.  Thank you in advance.

I've looked through previous questions but I wasn't able to find one that fully helped/explained where I'm getting stuck. I have a dictionary that stores team members(names, phone, jersey) and need to be able to write this to a file. Below is what I currently have, when I run this I get the error `AttributeError:'dict' object has no attribute 'getname'`.

```
class Member:
    def get name(self):
        return self.name
    def get phone(self):
        return self.phone
    def get jersey(self):
        return self.jersey

members={}
def saveData(members, filename):
    filename=input("Filename to save:")
    outFile=open(filename,"wt")
    for x in members.keys():
        name=members[x].getname
        phone=members[x].getphone
        jersey=members[x].getjersey
        outFile.write(name+","+phone","+jersey+"\n")
    print("Data Saved")
    outFile.close()
```

Comment: can you show me what members is?

Comment: This can't possibly be your real code. `def get name(self):` throws a SyntaxError. And we can't really help without knowing what `members` is.

Answer (score 1):

### Member class

You've put a space in the function name, so it won't work.
Too, you don't seem to have an `__init__` function.

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, jersey):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.jersey = jersey
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_phone(self):
        return self.phone
    def get_jersey(self):
        return self.jersey
```

Anyway, it's a lot easier that just don't make these get functions; the user can get the variables of a class using the dot syntax.

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, jersey):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.jersey = jersey
```

*shell:*

```
>>> member1 = Member("Dave", "123456789", "red")
>>> member.name
'Dave'
>>> member.phone
'123456789'
>>> member.jersey
'red'
```

### saveData function

It won't work, you should do this:

```
def saveData(members):           # don't include filename, it's going to be redefined later
    filename = input("Filename to save: ") # space at the end
    with open(filename, 'wt') as outFile:  # using with for files is recommended
                                           # then you don't need to close the file
      for x in members:            # you can directly iterate from a dict
          name = x.get_name()    # you didn't call the function at all
          phone = x.get_phone()  # members[x] not necessary
          jersey = x.get_jersey()
          outFile.write(name+", "+phone+", "+jersey+"\n") #missing + sign
      print("Data Saved")
```

### Working example

**__init__.py**

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, jersey):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.jersey = jersey
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_phone(self):
        return self.phone
    def get_jersey(self):
        return self.jersey

def saveData(members):
    filename = input("Filename to save: ")
    with open(filename, 'wt') as outFile:  

      for x in members:            
          name = x.get_name()    
          phone = x.get_phone()  
          jersey = x.get_jersey()
          outFile.write(name+", "+phone+", "+jersey+"\n")
      print("Data Saved")
```

**IDLE shell**

```
>>> members = [Member("Dave", "123456789", "red"),
           Member("Tom", "133742097", "yellow"),
           Member("Elisa", "122333444", "blue"),
           Member("John", "987654321", "blue")
          ]
>>> saveData(members)
Filename to save: output.txt
Data Saved
```

**output.txt**

```
Dave, 123456789, red
Tom, 133742097, yellow
Elisa, 122333444, blue
John, 987654321, blue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define getname, getphone in your Member class as follows:

```
class Member:
    def getname(self):
        return self.name
    def getphone(self):
        return self.phone
    def getjersey(self):
        return self.jersey
```

Then you can get values from getters in your **saveData** function :

```
name=members[x].getname()
phone=members[x].getphone()
jersey=members[x].getjersey()
```